# Capacitively coupled shunt resonator

Tags: filter, passive-networks, passive-filter

The diagram below shows a capacitively coupled parallel RLC resonator. Through simulations I observe that C2 and C3 influence the resonant frequency . I'd like to obtain the analytic expression for the resonance and eventually calculate S parameters. What would be the good approach to analyze this circuit  ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2felRj0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Just start at the beginning and work to the end really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of circuit very often has a high-Q resonator (R1,C1,L1) matched to low-impedance source and load (Z0) where Z0 is a pure resistance.
Pushed to an extreme (Z0 << R1), you can estimate the resonant frequency of the network by simply paralleling C1,C2,C3 (add their capacitances). The resulting resonant frequency \$ \frac {1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L_1(C_1+C_2+C_3)}} \$ will be lower than that of \$ \frac {1}{2 \pi  \sqrt{L_1C_1}} \$.

For the somewhat more general case at resonant frequency where Z0 value is similar to R1, you can find the series-to-parallel transform, changing the series network of Z0,C3 to its parallel equivalent Rp,Cp:
\$R_p =\frac { Z_0^2 + XC_3^2}{Z_0} \$ 
 \$XC_p=\frac{Z_0^2 + XC_3^2}{XC_3} \$
The network then becomes (at resonance) a simple, parallel RLC of lower Q than \$ R_1 C_1 L_1 \$.
Keep in mind that far from resonance, these transforms must be re-calculated for every frequency. This network's basic form is a high-pass filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 3rd order HPF with a resonant breakpoint that can be over or underdamped.  Although there are 4 reactive elements , C1 & C2 combine as a "capacitance transformer"  divider for voltage and effectively tune in parallel.

If Zo is the same on input and output, you lose 6dB automatically.

Depending on the RC breakpoint for \$\dfrac{(C1+C2)}{2Zo*(C1*C2)}\$ This can shift the resonances for \$\omega = 1/\sqrt{L1*(C1+C2+C3)}~~\$ such that C2 can have no effect if much smaller than C1,C2 but have high impedance across L1 and thus high voltage gain in the middle Q=R/ZL at the expense of low power from higher R.  [**e.g.**](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%2024389.095776063856%0Aw%20304%2080%20368%2080%200%0Ar%20432%2080%20432%20192%200%2050%0Ag%20304%20192%20304%20208%200%0AO%20304%2080%20352%2048%200%0A170%20144%2080%20112%2080%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%2032%2080%2096%20304%201%20Box%0Ac%20192%2080%20256%2080%200%200.000001%200%0Al%20304%2080%20304%20192%200%200.050045614924%200%0AB%20304%2032%20368%20256%201%20Box%0Ac%20368%2080%20432%2080%200%200.000001%200%0Ar%20192%2080%20144%2080%200%2050%0Ac%20368%20192%20368%2080%200%200.000009999999999999999%200%0Ar%20256%2080%20256%20192%200%2050000%0Aw%20256%2080%20304%2080%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20304%20192%200%0Aw%20304%20192%20368%20192%200%0Aw%20368%20192%20432%20192%200%0A)

The S11,S22 characteristics are straightforward impedance ratios.

But this RC:LRC:CR configuration is lossy and there are better filter arrangements for [**Bessel**](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%2024389.095776063856%0Al%2096%20112%20144%20112%200%200.012357699118317113%200%0Ac%20144%20112%20176%20112%200%205.124395663800956e-7%200%0Ac%20176%20112%20176%20224%200%200.000005600043724635943%200%0Al%20224%20112%20224%20224%200%200.0011308079524071555%200%0Aw%20176%20112%20224%20112%200%0Aw%20480%20112%20528%20112%200%0Ar%20528%20112%20528%20224%200%2050%0Ag%20176%20224%20176%20240%200%0Ag%20224%20224%20224%20240%200%0Ag%20528%20224%20528%20240%200%0A170%2096%20112%2064%20112%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AO%20528%20112%20576%20112%200%0AB%2096%2016%20224%20320%201%20Box%0AB%20224%2016%20352%20320%201%20Box%0Al%20224%20112%20272%20112%200%200.01235769911831711%200%0Ac%20272%20112%20304%20112%200%205.124395663800958e-7%200%0Ac%20304%20112%20304%20224%200%200.0000038249009950781616%200%0Al%20352%20112%20352%20224%200%200.0016556177495299343%200%0Aw%20304%20112%20352%20112%200%0Ag%20304%20224%20304%20240%200%0Ag%20352%20224%20352%20240%200%0AB%20352%2016%20480%20320%201%20Box%0Al%20352%20112%20400%20112%200%200.006030975746171499%200%0Ac%20400%20112%20432%20112%200%200.0000010500081983692388%200%0Ac%20432%20112%20432%20224%200%208.238466078878077e-7%200%0Al%20480%20112%20480%20224%200%200.007686593495701434%200%0Aw%20432%20112%20480%20112%200%0Ag%20432%20224%20432%20240%200%0Ag%20480%20224%20480%20240%200%0A), Butterworth, [**Chebychev**](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%2024389.095776063856%0Aw%20464%2096%20528%2096%200%0Ar%20528%2096%20528%20208%200%2050%0Ag%20144%20208%20144%20224%200%0Ag%20528%20208%20528%20224%200%0AO%20528%2096%20576%2096%200%0A170%2080%2096%2048%2096%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%2080%2048%20144%20272%201%20Box%0Ac%2080%2096%20144%2096%200%200.000013192041470974856%200%0Al%20144%2096%20144%20208%200%200.0006528822124338833%200%0AB%20144%2048%20208%20272%201%20Box%0Ag%20208%20208%20208%20224%200%0Ac%20144%2096%20208%2096%200%200.000010556358089500121%200%0Al%20208%2096%20208%20208%200%200.0006298616954950588%200%0AB%20208%2048%20272%20272%201%20Box%0Ag%20272%20208%20272%20224%200%0Ac%20208%2096%20272%2096%200%200.00001043395805048409%200%0Al%20272%2096%20272%20208%200%200.0006270301461078506%200%0AB%20272%2048%20336%20272%201%20Box%0Ag%20336%20208%20336%20224%200%0Ac%20272%2096%20336%2096%200%200.000010421701697644321%200%0Al%20336%2096%20336%20208%200%200.0006278858590489548%200%0AB%20336%2048%20400%20272%201%20Box%0Ag%20400%20208%20400%20224%200%0Ac%20336%2096%20400%2096%200%200.00001047153213412129%200%0Al%20400%2096%20400%20208%200%200.0006355740257458063%200%0AB%20400%2048%20464%20272%201%20Box%0Ag%20464%20208%20464%20224%200%0Ac%20400%2096%20464%2096%200%200.000010869353105562183%200%0Al%20464%2096%20464%20208%200%200.0008001602781674555%200%0A). etc.  It depends what you want for s parameter characteristics, then you design a filter accordingly or choose from the many standard configurations or learn how to do matrix filter caclulations.

Comment: Hey. I'm no sure that I understand your comment completely. Can you recommend me a resource ?

Comment: I linked 3 examples. You aren't specific about what your dont understand.  There are infinite resources

Comment: Hey you are right. I don't understand the expression for the RC breakpoint.